# Modify select elements of an array

Tags: c, indexing, blas

I know I can modify select elements with this code:

```
int* idx = ...
float* x = ...
float* a = ...
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    x[idx[i]] = a[i];
}
```

A more clear example is with the equivalent Python syntax:

```
x = zeros(8)
idx = array([1, 4, 5, 7, 2])
x[idx] = arange(5)*20
// x = [0, 20, 20, 0, 20, 20, 0, 20]
```

But I know that people have spent many hours optimizing simple for-loops like this. I've tried looking through the documentation for [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/), [BLAS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/BLAS_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009457) and [vDSP](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html) but haven't found a function that modifies select elements.

I have found functions that do [`x[i] = a[idx[i]]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_vgathr), essentially the inverse of what I want. What function modifies select elements in an array based on another array?

Comment: `idx[]` is a lookup table?

Comment: I am not sure if any optimization is possible in general. You could try forcing prefetching of `idx` and `a`, but that would likely be done already in this simple case. Does the sequence `idx[i]` satisfy any special properties?

Comment: @FiddlingBits No, it's just an `int *`. Could a lookup table also work? What functions would I look at?

Comment: @Pradhan No, no special properties.

Comment: @Scott Theres not a one-to-one correspondence between indices of `x` and `a` right?  How do you know, for example, if `i` is `3`, read from `a[3]` and store in `x[10]`, assuming `idx[3] == 10`.  Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the question...

Comment: @FiddlingBits I added a more clear Python description.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind it's not so black and white between optimized and not; worst case, you can always vectorize yourself. [Grand Central Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch) is you want to use; other libraries include [OpenMP](http://www.opengl.org).

Looking at a [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch#Examples) and running the following code, with two separate builds and uncommenting the appropriate sections,

```
NSLog(@"Start");

//dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        x[j[i]] = b[i];
    }
//});

NSLog(@"End");
```

we get the following results:

```
dispatch_async:
2014-07-25 21:12:23.509 swix[15390:303] Start
2014-07-25 21:12:26.649 swix[15390:303] End

Serial:
2014-07-25 21:12:55.719 swix[15428:303] Start
2014-07-25 21:12:58.860 swix[15428:303] End
```

We get 3.1 seconds both ways. Assuming the wikipedia example I lifted doesn't have any simple typos, I would guess that the compiler optimizes this simple loop to the extreme (especially given my optimization flag, `-Ofastest`.